# How can I remove the Maximise Minimise Buttons which appear on a DNN site

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I have a DotNetNuke website and I wish to remove the maximize, minimize buttons throughout the website. Is there any other way to do that without selecting "None" in the container settings? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method of doing this is through the settings of your modules.  Go to Settings -> Page Settings, then select 'None' at 'Collapse/Expand:'.

In older versions of DNN 'Allow Print?' was checked as the default and I would uncheck that box as well, to get rid of that icon.

Answer (score 2):

The min/max buttons are part of the container, so if you can edit the container file, you should be able to remove them pretty easily.

Find the `<dnn:VISIBILITY ... />` tag in the container file and remove it.  The container file will be in one of the `Portals` subdirectories (most likely `_default`, but possible in the directory of the specific site on which the containers are installed).  From that directory, find `Containers\[ContainerName]`, and then the `.ascx` file(s) for the container(s) you want to change.